# What do you call this Chinese Popcorn Cooking mechanism?

Tags: popcorn

In this video they have this [really cool popcorn pressure cooking thing,](https://youtu.be/FWMIPukvdsQ?t=327)

[image: Popcorn cooker]

Comment: "Stolen jet engine parts."

Comment: Pardon me for having some difficulty believing that the device is actually real and not a special effect.

Comment: Essentially it looks like a rudimentary puffing gun...and a potentially dangerous one at that.

Comment: Trademark "Chinese Popcorn Cooking Mechanism," just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Chinese Puffing Gun

You can see one for sale on [dhgate for $600](https://www.dhgate.com/product/electric-popcorn-machine-full-automatic-old/412762564.html#s1-4-1b;searl|2056986267)

[image]

You can see it in use here

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiD3YJD2RVU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baQT0pwvXKQ